# ISNA with multiple If condition not working - Getting error too many arguments in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Sheet 1]

Hello Team,
Working on to get OS edition where Edition is missing "#N/A" in Column B. So I've created a formula where in column "B" the values are "#N/A" then it will show by default edition which is matches in formula.

Formula :

```
=IF(ISNA(B2),(IF(Isnumber(search("2012",A2)),"Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit) - Assumption as DC","#N/A")),(IF(Isnumber(search("2008",A2)),"Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (64-bit) - Assumption as DC","#N/A")),(IF(Isnumber(search("2008 R2",A2)),"Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) - Assumption as DC","#N/A")),(IF(Isnumber(search("2016",A2)),"Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (64-bit) - Assumption as DC","#N/A")),"#N/A")
```

What should be actual result is define in column "D". When above formula is being used, it gives out error " **You have entered too many arguments"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first look at the syntax of the basic IF

```
=IF(logic_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Now let us expand this to test 5 values--

```
   =IF(logic_test, value_if_true,  IF(logic_test, value_if_true, =IF(logic_test, value_if_true,  IF(logic_test, value_if_true, IF(logic_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)  )  )  )  )
```

And begin to substitute the 1st logic test, and its final value were we to fail all the other tests--

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(B2)), B2,   IF(logic_test, value_if_true, =IF(logic_test, value_if_true,  IF(logic_test, value_if_true, IF(logic_test, value_if_true, "#N/A")  )  )  )  )
```

Then we can insert the remaining tests and their true_values--

```
=IF( NOT(ISNA(B2)), B2,  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2012",A2)), "12", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2008 R2",A2)), "8 R2",  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2008",A2)), "8", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2016",A2)), "16", "#N/A")  )  )  )  )
```

Notes: I have inverted the test for ISNA, to allow remaining IF-s to cascade.   I have shortened the values to be displayed which you will need to correct.  I have also tested for "2008 R2" before "2008", which is the correct sequence.